# Calculus II: Increasing / Decreasing Sequences

Tags: calculus

Okay, maybe I am just really bad with exponents or forgot how exponents work but how do you do these 2 problems, here's what I got so far. I need to state whether thee sequence is increasing, decreasing, and use the ratio rule and difference rule to figure it out.

> **Ratio rule**: $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} $
>
> **Difference rule**: $a_{n+1}-a_n$

1. I have to use difference rule here.

   $a_n=n-2^n$ from $n=0$ to $\infty $

   So here's what I have:

   $$\left[(n+1)-2^{n+1}\right] - (n-2^n)=\\=(1-2^{n+1}) + 2^n$$ after eliminating $n$

   From here on I am stuck, the answer apparently is $1 - 2^n$, don't know how.
2. I need to use ratio rule here.

   $a_n=ne^{-n}$ from $n=0$ to $\infty$

   So here's what I have:

   $$\frac{(n+1)e^{-(n+1)}}{ne^{-n}}$$

   And I am stuck here.

I am guessing all of this is just simplification, but I am just kinda lost.

Thanks.

Comment: I'll fix your question into latex format

Comment: For the first, use $2^{n+1}=2\cdot 2^n$.

Comment: And on (2), that should be $\frac{(n+1)e^{-(n+1)}}{ne^{-n}}$. As with (1), remember that $e^{-n-1} = e^{-n}e^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance.

Comment: Well, you indeed need to calculate those two quantities, but you must also see if they are bigger than certain something.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What sequence do you need to prove increasing or decreasing?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Yes I understand that part, just the algebra here I guess.

Comment: For 2 you don't need any of these rules, it is just a limit problem with a linear term in the numerator and an e-power in the denominator, it is obvious what that does if n goes to infinity. For 1 it is a "fight" between a linear term and an exponential term. That answer is also straight forward...

Comment: Ok so for the second one I found out what to do. I need to make e^-(n+1) into e^-n times e^-1, the top and bottom e^-n then cancel out, and I can take the remaining e^-1 out of the fraction in front. Then I have (n+1)/n left with e^-1 out front. (n+1)/n is the same as n/n + 1/n which would be 1+1/n, so the answer is (1+1/n)e^-1, which is < 1 so it's decreasing.

Comment: Now for the first problem I am still confused, I understand the exponent rules, but I am left with (1-2^n2^1)+2^n. Not sure how you can possibly simplify this anymore. I don't think you can factor anything out, and I am guessing you have to try to make the -2^n2^1 go away, but I don't know how :(

Comment: You are left with $1-2\cdot 2^n+2^n$, which is $1-2^n$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Are you distributing something, how does 2 times 2^n go away?

Comment: $1$ minus $2$ copies of $2^n$, plus $1$ copy of $2^n$. If you really want "algebra", $1-(2\cdot 2^n-2^n)=1-2^n(2-1)=1-2^n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\left[(n+1)-2^{n+1}\right] - (n-2^n)=\\=(1-2^{n+1}) + 2^n=1+2^n-2\cdot2^n
=1+2^n(1-2)=1-2^n<0,\forall n\ge1$$
therefore this sequence is decreasing.

$$\frac{(n+1)e^{-(n+1)}}{ne^{-n}}=
\frac{ne^{-(n+1)}}{ne^{-n}}+\frac{e^{-(n+1)}}{ne^{-n}}
=e^{-(n+1)-(-n)}+\frac{e^{-(n+1)-(-n)}}{n}=e+\frac{e}{n}>1, \forall n
$$
therefore this sequence is increasing.

Comment: Thank you, I now understand the first, had already figured out the second :)

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, you are nearly done-
1. You have (1- 2^(n+1)) + 2^n = 1- 2*2^n + 2^n = 1 - 2^n(2 - 1) = 1 - 2^n < 0 for all natural n.
2. You have [(n + 1)/n]*e^(-n-1 -(-n))= ( 1 + 1/n)*1/e = e + (e/n) > e > 1, for all natural n.